# How to mix PHP in HTML file

Tags: php, html

When I use iframe in HTML file that linked to test.php .. the result is OK

Test.php :

```
<?php     
   $host = "localhost";
   $user = "user";
   $pass = "pass";
   $database = "db";
   $koneksi = mysql_connect ($host,$user,$pass);

   mysql_select_db($database,$koneksi) or die ("error");

   $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM pengumuman"); 
   $i = 0;

   while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) { 
        echo "<li><a href='#'>".$row['judul']."</a></li>";
        $i++;
   } 

   mysql_close($koneksi); 
?>
```

But I do want to separate this test.php, so I mixed it in  my HTML file

```
<?php 
   $host = "localhost";
   $user = "user";
   $pass = "pass";
   $database = "db";
   $koneksi = mysql_connect ($host,$user,$pass);

   mysql_select_db($database,$koneksi) or die ("error");

   $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM pengumuman"); 
   $i = 0;

   while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) { 
?> 
   <li><a href='#'><?php $row['judul'] ?> </a></li>

<?php 
        $i++;
   }   
    mysql_close($koneksi); 
?>
```

And the result not OK anymore!
Truly, I'm new in web prog .. Can anyone help me ?

Comment: [Please, don't use mysql_* functions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php) in new code. They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). See the [red box](http://uk.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php)? Learn about [_prepared statements_](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php) will help you decide which.

Comment: you can not mix PHP in HTML file, but you can mix HTML in PHP file.

Comment: @metal_fan Ups I miss that .. But anyway there still no result in my HTML <Div>

Comment: Also, not sure why you're incrementing $i. You're not using it for anything.

Comment: @user2234261 Are you sure that $row['judul'] has a value?

Comment: @user1048676: $i not used yet .. I'll have it for item numbering ..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not possible:

```
<?php
   while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) { 
?> 
   <li><a href='#'><?php $row['judul'] ?> </a></li>

<?php 
        $i++;
   }
?>
```

But you can use the code below instead that:

```
<?php
$host = "localhost";
$user = "user";
$pass = "pass";
$database = "db";
$koneksi = mysql_connect($host,$user,$pass);

mysql_select_db($database,$koneksi) or die("error");

$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM pengumuman");
$i = 0;
?>

<!--
Other HTML Codes Here
//-->

<?php
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    echo "<li><a href='#'>" . $row['judul'] . " </a></li>";
    $i++;
}
?>

<!--
Another HTML Codes Here
//-->

<?php mysql_close($koneksi); ?>
```

But, I didn't check your PHP if it's right, for I'm chillin'.

---

I think this is want you want!
Create `open.php`:

```
<?php
$host = "localhost";
$user = "user";
$pass = "pass";
$database = "db";
$koneksi = mysql_connect($host,$user,$pass);

mysql_select_db($database,$koneksi) or die("error");

$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM pengumuman");
?>
```

Create `close.php`:

```
<?php mysql_close($koneksi); ?>
```

And the basename of your web page that included a PHP code must have a `.php` file extension, such like `div.php` because commonly, a PHP file must have a `.php` extension, but sometimes a web host server configured to allow a HTML file to read a PHP code, but it isn't normally. Let say your so called `<div>` HTML is in the `div.php` file:

```
<?php include 'open.php'; ?>
<div>
  <ol>
<?php
$i = 0;

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    echo "    <li><a href='#'>" . $row['judul'] . "</a></li>";
    $i++;
}
?>
  </ol>
</div>
<?php include 'close.php'; ?>
```

Comment: So, can you give me a sample code to put a MySQL field value in HTML <li> please ..

Comment: What do you mean, to input SQL, PHP `$_POST` Function, `<input>` tag or what? You can even write a HTML tag in PHP. Or it's this, `$select = "SELECT * FROM pengumuman"; $result = mysql_query("$select"); echo $select;` Sorry I didn't get what's in your mind.

Comment: I have MySQL data. Via test.php I can display the data. And it's work too when I call test.php in my HTML iFrame. But .. I want the result in my <Div> HTML file .. that's all

Comment: Is this what you've looking for: `<?php include 'test.php'; ?>` if you want to include `test.php` or `<?php require 'test.php'; ?>` to require it. You can even change the `include` or `require` to `include_once` or `require_once` if you want the specific file to be included/required once to a specific webpage.

Comment: Such `<div><?php include 'test.php'; ?></div>` or you can even style `test.php` before including it?

Comment: I think the best thing you could do is to seperate the opening from the closing, such what's added on the answer.

Comment: <div><?php include 'test.php'; ?></div> .. No, the result is empty space ..

Comment: Sorry, your next code was not worked for me .. There's only " . $row['judul'] . ""; $i++;}?> " in my <Div> box .. but thx anyway ..

Comment: Ah.. I see! Seems like your so called `div.html` couldn't read a PHP code, 'cause the server's not configured a HTML file to read a PHP code. The solution is to change the file extension into `.php` so your so called `div.html` will become `div.php` because there's a PHP code. I'll edited the answer after this.

Comment: You could even rename your file with `.phtml` file extension. For it's one of the specific extensions for a PHP file.

Comment: Hey thanks .. for your .phtml info ! My page displayed as I need !!

Comment: Gladly.. Maybe you could choose this thread as an answer to your issue, only if it satisfied you.

Answer (score 1):

you probably meant to add an echo before $row['judul']

```
<?php echo $row['judul']; ?>
```

simply putting the variable will not output it. Maybe you were thinking of short notation that is disabled by default

Comment: Yes, I missed it but there still no result in my HTML <Div>

Comment: I would print_r($row) and see what is there... make sure column name is capitalized the same as in the array - if there is a slight difference, it won't display

Comment: The test.php works fine if execute separately .. Means that it's OK with 'echo' and the column name either ..

Answer (score 1):

There are two things you have to take care in this case.

1) Add an echo before $row['judul']

```
<?php echo $row['judul']; ?>
```

2) Make sure that the extension of your file is '.php', if your file is test.html then change it to test.php and try.

NB: *If you don't want to change your file extension, you must change some server configurations for handling files with .html files. In apache you can achieve this by adding 'AddHandler' in httpd.conf file.*